# MAX14578 LDO connection not in use

Tags: usb

I want to use MAX14578, I've looked into datasheet (http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX14578AE-MAX14578E.pdf) and found it have an integrated LDO. But I don't need to use this LDO. Since I use BATT pin to power up this IC, can I don't use LDO? If yes, how should I connect this pins? to GND or leave floating?

Comment: Whatever you do, don't short it to ground. Remember the LDO is a power output - not a logic pin. I would just leave it floating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the same configuration as on the first "Typical Application Circuit" on page 9 of the datasheet.  Leave \$L_{OUT}\$ unconnected and connect \$V_B\$ to \$V_{BUS}\$ of the USB connector and via a 1\$\mu F\$ capacitor to ground.

If you're using the version with \$L_{OUT}\_SNS\$, connect it to \$L_{OUT}\$ and let them float together.

Comment: I'm using version AE with LOUT_SNS and LOUT. Should I also connect LOUT_SNS and LOUT together and leave floating or each pin separately floating?

Comment: I've amended my answer to address that point.